# How to move or export all Photos' library contents to a hierarchical by-date filesystem structure?

Tags: photos, catalina, photos.app

I have rather large Photos.app library consisting of >50 years of family photos and videos. With Catalina I've been really unhappy with some bugs that have lost a couple months of recent photos and video and Apple has remained mum on the issue.  I've decided that my data will be more safely stored in a filesystem hierarchical data system that I can use with other apps and can manually manage going forward.

How can I export an entire Photos.app `.photoslibrary` contents to such an organization (YYYY -> MM -> DD) while retaining timestamps and any other pertinent metadata?

Answer (score 2):

[Photos Takeout](https://www.photostakeout.com) app can export Year-wise, Album-wise and Date-wise folders from Photos for Big Sur, Catalina, Mojave and High Sierra, for libraries of up to 2 terabytes in size, while preserving folder hierarchy and metadata. It's not meant for iPhoto. [Disclosure: I do customer service at AIL, developer of this app.]

Comment: Interesting, I have closer to 4 TB of images and video... Will is go up to this much data?

Comment: It's been tested with a 2TB library. Theoretically it's library size-agnostic. For large libraries it takes long to load the assets (~40 min for a 1.4Tb library, if I remember correctly), but then exports are quite fast.